# How to display date on the x-axis in a NVD3 line chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to format the x-axis as date. I believe I am not passing the date data in the correct format. And I am getting an javascript error 'datetime is not defined'. I have included a fiddle demo here https://jsfiddle.net/hq8uv0sb/8/

```
nv.addGraph(function () {
            var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                .useInteractiveGuideline(true); 

            chart.yAxis.axisLabel('Price')
                .tickFormat(d3.format(''));

            chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
                 var dx = renderData()[0].values[d] && renderData()[0].values[d][0] || 0;
                return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx))
            });    

            chart.duration(500);

            chart.legend.maxKeyLength(100);

            d3.select('#dateChart')
                .datum(renderData())

                .call(chart);

            nv.utils.windowResize(function () {
                d3.select('#dateChart').call(chart)
            });

            return chart;
        });


function renderData() {
    var myData = {'Number': [datetime.date(2014, 7, 15), datetime.date(2014, 7, 16), datetime.date(2014, 7, 17)], 'Price': [100.0, 96.8645, 95.405]};

    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.Number.length; i++) {
        result.push({
            x: myData.Number[i],
            y: myData.Price[i]
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a working copy fiddle?

Comment: @AravindCheekkallur I am very new to this. How do I do this? Thanks!!

Comment: @AravindCheekkallur can you take a look at this? https://jsfiddle.net/hq8uv0sb/8/

Comment: I got the error in myData object.I would like to know what is datetime.date() is it a custom function or any library function?

Comment: @AravindCheekkallur Thanks for the help Aravind! you are right. I realized that's the problem. I change my data to string, and format the string from the x-axis.tickers. It solved the problem. Thanks you.

Comment: var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
var myData = {'Number': [format.parse("2014-7-15"), format.parse("2014-7-16"), format.parse("2014-7-17")], 'Price': [100.0, 96.8645, 95.405]};
This will solve your error